# How to use Zero Copy / Loan API when using ROS 2 services

Tags: ros2, action, services, ros-iron, intraprocess-communication

I can see many examples of using the Loan API in a pub/sub manner but can't see how to use it in the context of ROS 2 services (and maybe actions but that could possibly be incompatible)